# Show latest post from each author if post is not older than a month

Tags: php, wordpress, post, title, author

I have a list of the authors (Wordpress) on the site that appears on every page so the list exists outside of the loop.

I managed to show every authors' image with their names but I would like to get their latest post title that links to the post. The post title should only show when the post is not older than a month.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
<?php

        global $wpdb;
        $query = "SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users WHERE ID != '1' ORDER BY 'ASC' LIMIT 20";
        $author_ids = $wpdb->get_results($query);

        foreach($author_ids as $author) :

            // Get user data
            $curauth = get_userdata($author->ID);

            // Get link to author page
            $user_link = get_author_posts_url($curauth->ID);
            $post_link = get_permalink($curauth->ID);


            // Set default avatar (values = default, wavatar, identicon, monsterid)
            $main_profile = get_the_author_meta('mainProfile', $curauth->ID);
            $hover_profile = get_the_author_meta('hoverProfile', $curauth->ID);
            $award_profile = get_the_author_meta('awardProfile', $curauth->ID);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to create a new loop for you instead. It accepts a cool `date_query` argument since version 3.7. Untested, but should work.

EDITED:

```
$args =  array(
    'showposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => array(
                'year'  => date( "Y" ),
                'month' => date( "m", strtotime( "-1 Months" ) ),
                'day'   => date( "t", strtotime( "-1 Months" ) ),
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        )
) );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then you can just run a regular loop

```
// run the loop with $query
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo 'Latest post: ' . get_the_title();
    }
} else {
    // no posts
}
```

Comment: Hi avist, thanks. I tried your answer but the page doesn't load at all then. I stripped out my code from above just to make sure that it wouldn't interfere but still nothing. I also noticed that you wrote "$the_query" and not "$query". Wasn't sure which it should be but non the less it doesn't work either way.

Comment: @wind_kind, my bad, I've edited the query and changed the $args. It seems to be working for me, take a look and see if its your desired result